# Is there any alternative to goto in Python?

Tags: python, goto

Version: Python 3.7

```
for obj in group_obj.objects:
            bpy.ops.ed.undo_push()
        --> move_rotate(obj, T, T_0)
        |
        |   if check_if_cross_wall(obj):
        |       bpy.ops.ed.undo()
        ________from there


            count += 1
            accessableArea(obj)
```

Here is my code. My target is to check if the condition is satisfied, and if it is `True`, it will reverse the operation and goto the first line directly. I think goto is the most suitable way to do this, but I just know goto in C or C++, and Python does not have this.

Is there any other way to do this?

My code logic is:
Move & rotate the object, then check if it crosses the wall. If `True`, reverse the operation, then move & rotate again and check if it crosses the wall. If `False`,  it will save the current state and go to the next object.

Comment: Sorry I'm not English speacker, it should be "replace".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no "goto" in Python. To accomplish the sort of jump you describe, you can use a while loop with a `continue` statement to move back to the start of the loop and `break` to exit the loop, like this:

```py
for obj in group_obj.objects:
    bpy.ops.ed.undo_push()
    
    while True:
        move_rotate(obj, T, T_0)
        
        # as long as this is true, it will keep
        # moving back to the start of the loop
        if check_if_cross_wall(obj):
            bpy.ops.ed.undo()
            continue
            
        # Exit the loop when the condition
        # above wasn't true
        break

    count += 1
    accessableArea(obj)
```

Alternately, you could structure it like this, where it breaks when the condition is false and otherwise just does "undo" and starts over (no continue needed):

```py
for obj in group_obj.objects:
    bpy.ops.ed.undo_push()
    
    while True:
        move_rotate(obj, T, T_0)
        
        # exit the loop when the condition is false
        if not check_if_cross_wall(obj):
            break

        # otherwise undo and run the loop again
        bpy.ops.ed.undo()

    count += 1
    accessableArea(obj)
```

Comment: A minor quible - I think it would be more natural to have `if not check_if_cross_wall(obj): break`, and no explicit `continue` instead.

Comment: That would also work - I was trying to keep the structure as close to OP's as possible to make it easier to understand. Edited the answer to add that form too.

Comment: Your answer is comprehensive, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

No. If you want to jump in your code, you will have to use functions:

```
def func0(n):
    return n - 5

def func1():
    print(1)

def func2():
    print(2)

if func0(5) > 0:
    func1()
else:
    func2()
```